# Button didn't change its size based on the screen resolution

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

How can I make my Windows Store App look great on large resolutions? For example a Button - how can I change its font size based on the resolution? If I view my app on 13" the button looks OK, but if I view it on 27" display it looks very, very small. Isn't something to be used in the Windows store apps framework to adapt a button, textBlock, etc to the screen resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of screen scaling based on DPI... which makes your button the same physical size on both monitors, but totally ignores the fact that the user sits/stands much closer to one than the other.  Maybe someday we'll have a not-stupid scaling scheme that works based on subtended angles.

Large format monitors already have larger pixels, I suggest you simply opt out of display scaling in your application.  (But do respect the global system font size settings)

I'm not sure what the opt-out setting is in XAML (WPF), but in WinForms, I'd be changing the `AutoScaleMode` property.

Comment: I was testing the app on the emulator and that was confusing me. I ran the app on the local machine (24") and looks fine. If I want the button font size to be a little larger, I simply override the fontSize of the default button style and change it with a bigger value. This will reflect on all screens. Thanks @Ben Voigt

Answer (score 2):

Set `StretchDirection="Both"` & `StretchProperty="Fill"` in `ViewBox`

Comment: It is stretching the buttons, but the aspect ratio is lost. On landscape the width of the buttons is increased but the height remains the same.